# line break in phpexcel when I get comma

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpexcel

I want to make new line in one cell when i get a comma ',' in a string. How can i do that? 
Actually I concate three values from database,suppose here practices_codes are string like that:
`practice_codes= COLBY MEDICAL CENTRE,PARK HOUSE MEDICAL CENTRE,BLUEBELL LANE SURGERY,PRESCOT MEDICAL CENTRE;` 
So, i want to break a new line when i get ',' every time, that means the practices_codes should look like in excel-
COLBY MEDICAL CENTRE,
PARK HOUSE MEDICAL CENTRE,
BLUEBELL LANE SURGERY,
PRESCOT MEDICAL CENTRE.

Here is my code:
    `$sql_string .= 'CONCAT(pct_code,\' \', name," \n ",practice_codes) AS name`';
`$result = mysql_query("select $sql_string from my_table ");`

And in excel portion:

```
 $rowNumber = 5;
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        $col = 'B';
        foreach ($fields as $cell) {

            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($col . $rowNumber, $row[$cell]);
       $col++;
        }

        $rowNumber++;
    }
```

Comment: Replace the comma with a newline character ("\n"), set the cell styling to "wrap", and you'll probably want to set the row to autoheight as well

Comment: Solved it ! Thanks a lot.